# The mask codes appear different for same label in different images in fastai lesson 3-camvid.ipynb example. Is this an issue?

Tags: semantic-segmentation, fast-ai

I'm trying the fastai example, lesson 3-camvid.ipynb, and there is a verification in the beginning of the example, about the images and labels. Where we can see the original image and a mask (ground thruth semantic segmentation) from that original image.

Example, image 150 from the camvid dataset:

```
img_f = fnames[150]
img = open_image(img_f)
img.show(figsize=(5,5))
```

[image]

```
get_y_fn = lambda x: path_lbl/f'{x.stem}_P{x.suffix}'
mask = open_mask(get_y_fn(img_f))
mask.show(figsize=(5,5), alpha=1)
```

[image]

But, if I change the image, for example to image 250 from the camvid dataset:

[image]

The mask label changes, eg. the road label has a different color from the previous image:

[image]

Apparently, it matters the order in which each label occurs on each image.

**So, is this an issue? Is it something I should fix somehow?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official CamVid labels Road has to be the color as in the image 250.

[Camvid Class Labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVrKz.jpg)

You can leave the data set as it is, but if you looking for increasing model accuracy you can change the labels of the corresponding pixels. The Model is capable of identifying the road by other examples in data set.

Comment: Hi @Harish Vutukuri, I appreciate your answer. But, let me see if I understand, ok?

1 - About changing the labels. Is there anything in Fast.ai that ensures that the "road" label is always labeled with the same code, regardless of the order that appears in each frame?

2 -  Yes, the network seems to be really learning. But then I mean, some different information is passed on, but overall it doesn't matter, as most are expected?

Comment: Hi @ThiagoRTK, 1- As far as I know fast.ai doesn't provide such functionality. 2 - Basic idea is that there should be some false labels so that model can learn on that and make a decision, if the evaluation metric is too worse then we have to change the labels explicitly.